# calculation of variance

Tags: variance, count-data, biostatistics

Hi I have a question regarding calculation of variance of survey results.

Consider the following example. If 5 (x) people answered a survey which consists of 3 (y) yes (1) or no (2) questions. You would have something like:

```
    Y1 y2 y3

X1  1. 0. 0

X2  0. 1. 1

X3. 1. 1. 1

X4. 0. 1. 1

X5. 0. 0. 1
```

If I calculate a total score by calculating the proportion of yes (1) for each respondent and then average this across all respondent. In this case I will calculate the proportion for respondent x1, x2,...,x5. Then take the sum of all and divide by 5. If I calculate a variance for this total, I am wondering if I have to take into consideration the within respondent variance? Or can I just calculate the across respondent variance as the total variance??

If anyone can help that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to take the within respondent variance into account.  In many examples, multiple questions like this indicate strength of agreement with the concept, and you can regard the true concept score as consisting of 0 (all 0s) to 3 (all 1s).

Comment: Hi Does this mean that rather have each person's answer to a question be a random variable having binomial distribution. The random variable becomes the strenght of agreement with the concept. If that's the case what would be the distribution of this new random variable, it's not binomial. Is it poisson? Thank you for your prompt rseponse this is really helpful!

Comment: Hi another method I am thinking of is just to count the total number of yes (1) within that one concept for all patients to create a score. We are not averaging across patients nor questions. If this is the case would the variance have to take into consideration both across respondent and within respondent variations? Would the variance calculation be different from the one above? Thank you.

Comment: You would need to take into account the across-patient variation, but not the within-patient variation.

Comment: I am sorry to bug you again. I have just one more question. If I take the proportion for each question and then take the average for each question, do I take both within and across into consideration? To my understanding I would need to. Is this correct?              I am wondering in all three cases do I start my justification with xi=0 if person i answered no and 1 if yes where x is bin(n, p). Or should I start the justufication with another method. Thank you. Let me know if this is unclear, I have it written out using word formula but it is not copying and pasting correctly into here.

Comment: I would do the addition across first (leading to a score of 0 to 3). This gives you the score for each xi. Then you average across the xi to get the average score (and calculate the variance).

Comment: I would have to average the 0-3 first by the number of y first. We have cases where there is only y1 and y2. Then I can sum up the averaged for each xi and then rdivide by number of xi or I. Will that change anything?

Comment: If you have missing data, you will need to handle it in some way. I don't understand the dimensions of your problem or your data to know whether you can drop cases with missing data, whether you should impute them, or whether you can average them.